# Linux Test Project 'nfs_stress' nfs01 'RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted'

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, networking

I am trying to set up a docker image, based on Ubuntu, to have the [Linux Test Project](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp) ready to use. When I try and fire off the `network > nfs > nfs_stress > nfs01` I get an *iproute2* error

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
nfs01 1 TBROK: ip li add name ltp_ns_veth1 type veth peer name ltp_ns_veth2 failed
```

The `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted` is the *iproute2* error and the `ip li add name ltp_ns_veth1 type veth peer name ltp_ns_veth2` is the command that the `nfs01` script is trying to run.

Any dea what the *iproute2* error could be? And how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran through this now. The issue is in the magic word veth. Check if you have CONFIG_VETH enabled in your kernel. But it could be something else of course. But also related to some malfunction in virtual network driver.

I was quite far away from your setup. I tried to run these onto embedded linux with no shell...Only BusyBox :-). Good luck!